# How come when I click a button to create another one, the first one can no longer be clicked?

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

I was following a tutorial on how to use surfaceView for an android app. Originally there is only one button `swapBtn` that animates either the black or white circle. However, I tried to modify it so once I clicked it, another button `other` would appear. However, once I do this, the first button `swapBtn` can no longer be clicked to switch between animating the white and black ball. I also get a error in the debug console saying:

Thread[<1> main] (Suspended ( exception NullPointerException))

How can I fix this so that I can show the second button while still being able to click the second button. Here is the relevant code. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_surface_view);

    swapBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonswap);


    surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mysurface);
    holder = surface.getHolder();

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    swapBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            /** SWAP ANIMATION LEFT OR RIGHT CIRCLE*/
            left = !left;

            if (other.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if(other.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `other` isn't declared or initialized anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: both of the buttons are declared outside of the method. Eclipse shows no errors for the code

Comment: Ok, it's declared, but where are you initializing it? E.g., where's `other = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonother);`?

Comment: I haven't initialized yet. I thought I would only need that once I start actually using the button. I went back and initialized it and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: The variable `other` still needs to point to an object before you call methods on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare "other" button:

```
other = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonother);
```